# How to know variables from different..."namespaces"?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, adsense

How can I reach some variable declared in another place from within an external javascript file ?

Suppose in an html file I have the following

```
<head>
 <script>
   var a = 'something';
 </script>
<head>
<body>
<iframe src="otherfile.html"/>
</body>
```

and inside otherfile.html, in the  section, I have

```
alert(a);
```

How can I make sure I get an alert message saying "something" ?

I think Google Adsense does this, their code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "youdontneedtoknowthis";
google_ad_slot = "5404192644";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

How can the script in http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js know those variables (e.g. google_ad_client) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when a variable is defined without `var` it is said to exist in global scope. When your JS is loaded into your page, it is aware of any variables that exist globally at that time. So, what google is doing is defining some variables and then loading in an external script.

Comment: I always thought that defining it *with* var, outside a function, defines it in the global scope. When using it without defining it with `var` I figured you're actually creating a property of the window object.  Don't know where I got that info from...

Comment: hm... interesting. you may be right. but either way, that variable is available globally.

Comment: if you do this _outside_ a function, it _is_ a global variable. Unless, of course, that "outside" is really inside another function (eg. anonymous one). That is why it is better to always add `var` when initializing variables and state explictly when you need to transform something into global variable (eg. by `window['some_variable'] = 'some value'`).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter.

All `<script>` blocks in the page share the same context and variables.

Answer (score 0):

The script can just assume that those variables will be set. They must be because they are needed. The script can check if they are undefined and fail gracefully (do nothing) when they are not. The variables are not in another namespace.