# Using javascript variables from another function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know variables from different…“namespaces” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024748/how-to-know-variables-from-different-namespaces)

I have a webphone integrated into our webpage, and when a call comes in, a javascript function records the caller's number (e.g. `01234 123456`) and saves it as the variable `inCallingNum`.

I need to use this variable in a different function which sends information to a php page and stores it on our database.

Is it possible to access the javascript variable from another function at all, and if not what is the easiest way to get around it?

Edit: This is the code I have, which currently captures the inCallingNum variable

```
    function webphonetojs(varr)
        {
            var eventNotify = '' + varr; 
            //alert("eventNotify = "+eventNotify);
            displaystatus('WEBPHONE SAY: '+eventNotify);

            initcheck();
            var chanelStat = applethandle.API_GetStatus(1); //  get line status
            var chanelStatus = chanelStat.replace(/\s+/g,'');
            if (chanelStatus == 'Ringing')
            {
                var incomming = eventNotify.slice(eventNotify.lastIndexOf(",")+1, eventNotify.length);
                if (incomming == '2')
                {
                    var inCallingNum = eventNotify.split(",", 4); inCallingNum = inCallingNum.toString();
                    inCallingNum = inCallingNum.slice(inCallingNum.lastIndexOf(",")+1, inCallingNum.length);
                    displaystatus('CALLER IS: '+inCallingNum);

}
}
}
```

Comment: This is a pure javascript question, retagged. Please don't use false tags to make your question more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the variable if you declare it in global scope and just use it in both funstions.

Comment: personally I hate using global vars and avoid them wherever possible, but without seeing any of OP's code, I guess your solution is the most viable! :)

Comment: Hi s-buzz, i have updated my question with the code I am using. Could you tell me what I would need to move/change to be able to access it globally please?

Comment: Declare `var inCallingNum;` before declaring the function. Inside the function use it without the `var` keyword. If you do so you use the global var `inCallingNum` and not the local one.

Comment: Thanks very much, works great :) I think I need to try and learn javascript alot better soon

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** : Populating the global scope is a *bad* idea. Better to return the variable from the method you are using and working with it. Having said that, this is how you put it in the global scope

```
var bVar = '';

function a() {
  alert(bVar);
}

function b() {
  bVar = 'B just used it';
}

b();
a();
```

Since `bVar` is in global scope, any method can now access it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the scope of the variable `inCallingNum`.

If it has public scope then you could be able to access it in another function.
If it has private scope then you need to either change it to public (or global) or add getter method to it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You just have to store the value in a variable that is outside of the scope of a function. So you declare a global javascript variable by putting the "var varName = '';" outside the braces of a function and use that variable.