# How to access the variable from one function to another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have prompt dialog box which take Email value and need to pass the Email variable in another function Email(). Here is my code.

```
function promptMessage() {
    public var Email = prompt("Enter your Email :", "");
}
function Email(){
    alert("Email Address is " +Email); //Email from promptMessage() function 
}
```

Comment: declare Email in global scope..

Comment: either make it a global variable or have a helper function take a parameter that you can pass it to.

Comment: What is `public` doing there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using javascript variables from another function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028489/using-javascript-variables-from-another-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
function promptMessage() {
    return prompt("Enter your Email :", "");
}
function Email(email){
    alert("Email Address is " +email); //Email from promptMessage() function 
}
Email(promptMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it outside of the scope of the functions and dont use a function name as a variable name this will leed to nightmares:

```
var EmailAddr;

function promptMessage() {
     EmailAddr = prompt("Enter your Email :", "");
}
function Email(){
    alert("Email Address is " +EmailAddr); //Email from promptMessage() function 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring the Email variable inside a function(in local scope), that's why it is not accessible outside of this function. Instead, define it outside like this as a global var :

```
var email;
function promptMessage() {
    email = prompt("Enter your Email :", "");
}
function Email(){
    alert("Email Address is " +email); //Email from promptMessage() function 
}
```